# Drawing a cube with turtle graphics - How to determine positions of vertices?

Tags: python, 3d, turtle-graphics

I found this code for drawing a cube with Python turtle Graphics and I realised I have no idea how I would go about doing this myself. The values used seem to suggest an underlying system for determining the positions of the vertices. (Is it like isomorphic paper?).

Could someone please explain how the program works, in terms of the geometry used? I'm not looking the get heavily into transformations of 3d coordinates using trig. etc., but it would be great to have a  system or heuristic to get me started with drawing simple 3d shapes using Turtle Graphics.

```
import turtle


turtle.setup(1440,900)
turtle.bgcolor('black')

# Setup
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.penup()
t.goto(-40,-50)
t.pendown()

# Yellow Square
t.color('yellow')
t.begin_fill()
t.forward(100)
t.left(90)
t.forward(100)
t.left(90)
t.forward(100)
t.left(90)
t.forward(100)
t.left(90)
t.end_fill()

# Orange Parallelogram 
t.color('orange')
t.begin_fill()
t.left(135)
t.forward(60)
t.right(45)
t.forward(100)
t.left(45)
t.backward(60)
t.end_fill()

# Red Parallelogram
t.color('red')
t.begin_fill()
t.penup()
t.forward(60)
t.right(45)
t.right(90)
t.pendown()
t.forward(100)
t.right(45)
t.forward(60)
t.end_fill()
t.penup()
t.color('black')
t.forward(100)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: A cube is a 3D object and each vertex has 3D coordinates comprised of X, Y, &  Z values. To draw it with 2D graphic primitives, such as those in Python's turtle graphics module, will require converting these vertices into 2D. This is called a "projective" transformation. The simplest one is to just throw away the Z value in what is called a "flat" projection. Another way is to divide each X & Y value by Z (and throw away the Z), which is a so-called "perspective projection" because things further away will appear smaller.